PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: 3 arguments are required
WordPress version: 6.5.3
PHP version: 8.1
Astra theme version: 4.6.14
Nginx version：1.26.0
When I set the site language to Chinese and use the theme's search function, it encounters an error，looks like this:
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: 3 arguments are required, 2 given in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/core/common-functions.php:949
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/core/common-functions.php(949): sprintf()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/core/common-functions.php(1026): astra_get_taxonomy_banner_legacy_layout()
#2 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): astra_archive_page_info()
#3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/core/theme-hooks.php(429): do_action()
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/astra/search.php(27): astra_archive_header()
#7 /var/www/html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('...')
#8 /var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('...')
#9 /var/www/html/index.php(17): require('...')

When I switch the site language to English, the theme's search function works fine again.Or I attempted to delete files in the server directory
rm -rf /var/www/html/wp-content/languages/themes/*
and now the search function is working correctly again.I want the site language to be Chinese and the search function to work properly. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

It seems to be a known issue with the Astra theme, see: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-on-searching/


Try to clear cache 2)

Update the PHP version to 8.3

If both the above points are not helpful. Try to add the following code in the child theme:
add_filter( 'astra_theme_defaults', 'astra_theme_defaults_custom', 99, 1 ); 
function astra_theme_defaults_custom($defaults) {
     $defaults['section-search-page-title-custom-title'] = 'Title of Search title in default language:';
     return $defaults;
}




Where do I clear the cache, and how do I do it?

@zhilong clear the browser Cache as well as clear from website if you are Cache plugin. Moreover, you can check website in google chrome's incognito mode. Hope it will help.
